# Why does `syntax keyword` command not highlight keywords when present in ~/.vimrc?

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I want that whenever any file I am editing contains the word `TODO` or `LATER` anywhere it should be syntax highlighted with the `Todo` highlight group.

I have the following in ~/.vimrc.

```
colorscheme elflord
syntax keyword Todo TODO LATER
```

I have the following in a text file called foo.txt.

```
TODO foo
LATER bar
```

When I open this file (`gvim foo.txt`) I see that the elflord colorscheme is applied but the `TODO` and `LATER` are not highlighted.

However, when I enter `:syntax keyword Todo TODO LATER` in the command line mode, the highlighting works.

- Why does the command not work when it is in `~/.vimrc` but works when manually entered in the command line mode?
- How can I make it work from `~/.vimrc`? I would like all my custom configuration to be at one place in `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: My psychic powers tell me this is a per-buffer setting and you should use an autocmd to run it in each new buffer.

Comment: @Kevin You seem to be right. The following command in ~/.vimrc works for me: `autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead * syntax keyword Todo TODO LATER`